# Thunar file manager: Sort by column keyboard shortcut?

Tags: xfce, thunar

I'm using Xfce 4.3 and the lightweight Thunar file manager. I often change file listings between Sort by Date Modified and Sort by Name. But it seems the only way to do this is by clicking the column header with the mouse, which slows down productivity.

Is there anyway to activate these sort mechanisms using the keyboard? They are not listed in any of the menus.

Comment: Filed as [bug 9301](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9301)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the steps in [this faq entrty](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/faq#%20How%20do%20I%20assign%20different%20keyboard%20shortcuts?)

Comment: my apologies but I am unable to accept any answer at this time since I do not use or have access to Xfce any longer. If anyone confirms that this works please comment and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the 'Arrange items by' (which can all have shortcuts assigned) are visible when viewing the detailed list view, and invisible menu options do not respond to keystrokes. I'm not sure if this is an xfce or GTK issue.

What I do is switch to compact view (ctrl-3) perform your sorting keystroke then switch back to detailed list (ctrl-2). Annoying but somehow still faster than reaching for the rat..